# set JList to fill the entire size of the component it is added to

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jlist

below is my code for creating the JList. When it is created in a standalone JFrame the JList fills the entire frame. However, when I create it as a JPanel and add it to the JFrame it is not filling the size of the component, Why?

```
public class ListBranchesInterface extends JPanel {
private Library theLibrary; // reference to back end
private ArrayList<LibraryBranch> branches;
private DefaultListModel dlm;
private JList list;
private JScrollPane scroll;

public ListBranchesInterface(Library theLibrary) {
    this.theLibrary = theLibrary;
    branches = new ArrayList<LibraryBranch>();
    branches.addAll(theLibrary.getLibraryBranches());

    Iterator<LibraryBranch> iter = branches.iterator();
    dlm = new DefaultListModel();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {

        dlm.addElement(iter.next().toString());

    }
    list = new JList(dlm); // create a JList from the default list model

    scroll = new JScrollPane(list, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS); // add a scroll pane
                                                        // to the JList

    add(scroll);
    setVisible(true);

}
```

Comment: `(JPanel.)setVisible(true)`  This will happen by default for any component added to a visible container (e.g. a `JFrame` once `setVisible(true)` is called).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the default layout manager of a `JFrame`'s *content pane* is `BorderLayout` and adding directly to it would fill the entire available space (i.e., center) of the frame's content pane. On the other hand, the default layout manager of a `JPanel` is `FlowLayout`.  The `FlowLayout` class puts components in a row, sized at their preferred size. So adding the `JList` to a `JPanel` would not fill the entire available space.

Answer (score 0):

From @kavka I derived the answer... The fact is Change to Border Layout.

```
JPanel As_list_panel = new JPanel();
As_list_panel.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200);    //I think this line is unecessary. check it                                      
As_list_panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
```